# Changes to Shopify Brooklyn Menu

Tags: html, css, menu, shopify, liquid

I'm busy setting up a Shopify store and would like to do the following

I would like to move the menu that is currently on the right to the middle and put the logo above the menu. I have looked around and can't find anything that works.

Example of what I want it to look like
[image]

I would also like to make the menu items sticky on scroll...

Can someone please advise me how I could go this with the Brooklyn theme?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below:

1. Go to Online Store->Theme->Edit code
2. Asset->theme.scss->paste bellow code in bottom of file

```css
.site-header{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```